# memcpy is not copying the data inside structs

Tags: pointers, struct, memcpy

I am new c-programmer. I am developing a small student database. The database consists of structs student. Each student has a firstname, lastname and matriculation number. One method is to delete a student with a matriculation number. So i searched for matriculation number into the dynamic array. Then I tried to copy the elements that are before the element to remove and the elements that are after the element to remove into another dynamic array. The first problem is the copy-process. It does not work, although i using memcpy.When i have three elements and i delete one then i found 2 structs without informations. I means 2 empty structs in temp contains no Informations (like lastname......). I dont know why memcpy is not working.
The second problem consists in the segmentation fault when i try to free my dynamic memory. What i am doing is after copying the new struct into temp. I free db. Then i set db=temp. So normally db is pointing to the new dynamic array. But I also get segmentation fault Here is code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef int bool;
#define  true 1
#define  false 0
struct student{
    char lastname[20];
    char firstname[20];
    int  mNr;
   char courseOfStudy[20];
   char nationality[20];
};

struct student * db;
struct student * ptrDb;
int size=0;
void createDb(int s){
    size=s;
    db= (struct student *)malloc(100*sizeof(struct student *));
    ptrDb=db;
    printf("database was created\n");
}
struct student getData(char lastname [], char firstname[], int matNr,   char courseOfStudy [], char nationality []){
    struct student st;
    memcpy(st.lastname,lastname,strlen(lastname));
    memcpy(st.firstname,firstname,strlen(firstname));
     st.mNr=matNr;
    memcpy(st.courseOfStudy,courseOfStudy, strlen(courseOfStudy));
    memcpy(st.nationality,nationality,strlen(nationality));
    printf("%s,%s,%d\n",st.lastname,st.firstname,st.mNr);
    return st;
 }
 //coping input by reference
 void insert_student(struct student *  st){
    *ptrDb=*st;
    ptrDb++;
}

bool delete_entry(int matNr){
    int new_size=size-1;
    int indexToRemove;
    int i;
    printf("look for the matriculation number: %d in the  Database:\n",matNr);
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        if((db+i)->mNr==matNr){
            printf("student found\n");
            printf("new database size: %d:\n",new_size);
            indexToRemove=i+1;
            struct student * temp = (struct student *) malloc((new_size)*sizeof(struct student));
            memcpy(temp,db,indexToRemove-1);// copy all elements before indexToRemove
            memcpy(temp+indexToRemove,db+indexToRemove+1,size-indexToRemove+1);//copy all elements after indexRemoved
            int j=0;
            for(j=0;j<new_size;j++){
                puts("YES");
                 printf("lastname: %s, firstname:%s, enrollment nr:%d\n",(temp+j)->lastname,(temp+j)->firstname,(temp+j)->mNr);
        }
            free(db);//free the old dynamic memory
            db=temp;//now db is pointing to the new dynamic memory
            free(temp);//I dont need temp any more, free it
            return 1;

    }
}   

return 0;
```

}

Comment: yes it has been update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are probably multiple problems here, `free(temp)` at the end of the delete function is wrong.  You reassigned the variable, but now db and temp point to the same memory which you subsequently free.

If your free() implementation zaps memory (this is not typically for most standard malloc/free implementations), this could cause your problem.  If it does not, then something else is wrong as well.

Comment: I want that temp is not pointing any more to the new allocated memory. Because like you say i only need that db points to new memory. But how can i do it

Comment: @amitakCs: `temp = NULL;`.  Please accept the answer if it answers your specific problem.

Comment: the second problem is solved. But what about the first problem?

Comment: @amitakCs: Well, more information is needed.  Does it still happen after the bad free is removed?  Do the structs before or after the item to be removed get nuked?  Are the pointers (db array) being nuked or are the structures (*db) being nuked? Does it happen every time? Oh, and I think you have an order of operation problem on the third argument to the second memcpy--should be `size-(i+1)`. (BTW, you don't need to set temp to NULL, it is an automatic variable and you are returning immediately, so the temp variable is destroyed).

Comment: well, it happens every time. It s just not copying. After the delete-operation  the data is also lost. I mean the content of all structs. What is working fine is that i am finding the right object (struct) to remove. But the copying process is false. My idea is just copying all elements before the object to be removed and put them into another Array. Same Thing for the elements after the Object to remove. So at the end i get an dynamic array containing all element excepting the element to be removed.

Comment: All the code after (struct student * temp = (struct student *) malloc((new_size)*sizeof(struct student));) is false

Comment: @amitakCs: I"m not sure what you mean by "false".  But I think the size argument to memcpy is wrong.  ((size-(i+1)*sizeof(*db)) and ((i-1)*sizeof(*db)).  You were copying the number of elements in your array in bytes instead of in your structs.

Comment: Perhaps I should teach you how to fish.  After you compile this (with debugging turned on and optimization turned off), run the program under gdb or the debugger of your choice.  Step through the delete function and check the arguments to each function (eg malloc, memcpy, etc) and inspect the db and temp arrays before and after each memcpy instruction.  This should show you quite clearly what is going on.  Alternately you can scatter prints of the critical data after each statement.  Anyway, if you still have problems update the source since I don't know what changes you might have made.

Comment: well, i decided to avoid temporary memcopy. So i used normal assignement temp[i]=db[i].  I created a db containing three structures . I decided to delete the struct at the middle  (db[1]). Then i began Assignment-operations. So temp[0]=db[0] was a wrong assignement because db[0].mNr=34 and i found temp[0].mNr=0. It means that copying a structure from one array to another by assignement-operator does work.